# Update parent state object in child and send that object back to parent

Tags: reactjs

I have the following parent/child component. In Parent I have a `report` object that gets set to the parent state as `this.state.updateReport`. This then gets sent to Child via props. In Child, I store the report in `this.state.childEditedReport` and make changes to it.

```
class Parent extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
        super(props)

        this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);

        this.state = {
            updateReport: undefined
        };
    }


    updateParentState() {
        this.setState({
            updateReport: Report (report is coming from somewhere else)
        });
    }

    render() {
        return <Child report={this.props.updateReport} />
    }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { childEditedReport: this.props.report }
    }

    //do some update on the report via `this.props.childEditedReport`

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              Child
            </div>
        )
    }
}
```

How can I send this changed report object back upto Parent as the updated version of the parent's `this.state.updateReport`?

Answer (score 0):

First of all, you need to store the `report` props that came from parent component in child constructor states using [componentWillReceiveProps](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#unsafe_componentwillreceiveprops) then you need to use [liftStateUp](https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html)

I did an example with `comments` explanation beside each code will help to understand how does lift state works from `Child` to `Parnet`.

```js
class App extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props)
   //this.handler = this.handler.bind(this);
    this.state = { 
          updateReport: 'Parent Data' 
          };
  }
  componentDidMount(){
    setTimeout(()=>{
        this.setState({updateReport: 'data receive from asyn call'})
    },2000); // let consider the asyn call takes a 2 sec.
  }
  //  updateParentState() {
    //    this.setState({
       //     updateReport: Report (report is coming from somewhere else)
     //   });
   // }

    update= (data) =>{
      this.setState({ updateReport: data}) // setting data that Received from child in parent State
    }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <h1>Parent Component </h1>
        Let's consider that the asyn takes 2 sec to set the date in the state
        updateReport: <b>{this.state.updateReport}</b>
        <Child report={this.state.updateReport} liftStateUp={this.update} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class Child extends React.Component {
    constructor(props) {
      super(props);
      this.state = { childEditedReport: 'empty' }
    }
    componentWillReceiveProps(nextProps){
      if(nextProps.report !== this.props.report){
        this.setState({childEditedReport: nextProps.report}) // setting the data in state
      }
    }

    //do some update on the report via `this.props.childEditedReport`
    someChanges = () =>{
      let update = this.state.childEditedReport; // updating new data
      this.props.liftStateUp(update);
    }

    render() {
        return (
            <div>
              <h1>Child Component</h1>
              Check ChildEditedReport State: <b>{this.state.childEditedReport}</b><br />
              <button onClick={()=>this.setState({ childEditedReport: 'New Data Received' })}>Make some Change</button> Step one<br /> 
              <button onClick={this.someChanges}>Lift State To Parent</button> Setp two
            </div>
        )
    }
}
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'));
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/react/15.1.0/react-dom.min.js"></script>

<div id='root'></div>
```

Comment: Couple of things: Why do I have to initialise child state it in `ComponentWillReceiveProps` instead of in the `constructor`? Also, when we do `let update = this.state.childEditedReport;` with the updates, does this give us the same instance of the report object passed from Parent, just updated... or is it a new instance?

Comment: You don't have to use `ComponentWillReceiveProps` unless if you are doing an HTTP request to set the `updateReport` state data in the parent component, so the HTTP request call might take parts of seconds and that's why we use `componentWillReceiveProps` so when the props data arrives in child component it I'm setting the props into a state. you can make `childEditedReport: props.report` it works also.

Comment: Cheers. Could you answer my second question?

Comment: In the `someChanges` function I'm passing the `childEditedReport` state 
 to the parent component `updateReport`  state whatever is the changes happen, as you can see in my code above I'm just changing the state to be `'New Data Received'` so this will passing it to the parent component with `liftStateUp` function.

Comment: This is not a good pattern. Firstly it makes no sense to have the updatedReport stored in two places, because then you have two potential sources of truth down the line. No reason here why state shouldn't be stored on the parent. Secondly, why would you want to click a button to lift the state up when you can just do it directly as I describe below? Thirdly, componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated so if you absolutely HAVE to do it this way (you don't) use getDerivedStateFromProps.

Comment: @JonnyRathbone could you edit your answer to be a bit more clear as to what you mean?

Comment: `updatedReport` updates the state in the parent though. so onClick you end up having one source of truth, because parent Report gets updated, no?

Comment: You don't have to store `updatedReport` in two places or to click a button but for example be clear and understandable I'm passing the parent state to child component, you can pass anything to child component like `report={'this instead of updatedReport state'}` as well for `liftStateUp` function you need to trigger with an action it's not a condition to use a button. Finally, this isn't my way, it's how React works as they describe here https://reactjs.org/docs/lifting-state-up.html as well for passing state between parent and child components. can you show us an example of your answer?

Comment: Sorry for late reply - if you're not reliant on the button then it's fairly similar but if this was the case then there is no need to have any state on the child component. Make the changes using functions which are written on the app component, and change the app state. Use it in the child component directly as props. You aren't doing what the docs suggest - 'lifting state up' is a design decision, not a function. It means holding state in lowest common ancestor. If it needs to be in App because other components will use it as props, hold it only in app. Else hold it only in the child.

Comment: @ZeroDarkThirty if you have the same state held in two places, you have two sources of truth and you are doing something wrong. If child has it available from parent, then just use it from the parent! That's what props are for.

Answer (score -2):

You can't, shouldn't and won't. React works on a process of unidirectional flow of data - pass things down as props to children, but there's no way to pass them back up. Instead, write the function that makes alterations in your parent component, and pass this function as props to your child. Your child component can then call the function as you need to, and it will update the parent's state. Your parent will then re-render the child with the new data, meaning that making any changes in your child component will hopefully be unnecessary.